# How to customize data frame printing chunk-by-chunk?

Tags: r, knitr

I am aware of the `df_print` option in the RMarkdown yaml header.  But is there a way to customize the printing on a chunk-by-chunk basis?  I have a list of data frames that I want printed with the `tibble` print method (the output I see when I print from the console) instead of lots of paged data frame prints in the chunk output.  Thanks!

Comment: Uhm,... end the chunk with: `tibble:::format.tbl_df()` with the data-frame you want to print?

Comment: @Mossa.  `tibble:::print.tbl_df(as_tibble(iris))` throws an error for me.  Any suggestions?  The error message is "Error in NextMethod() : 'NextMethod' called from an anonymous function".

Comment: I've tried it myself.. and yeah.. It doesn't work. I've got nothing to add unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you refer to the output, do you mean how it looks after knitting to HTML? Do you by any chance mean this output:

````
---
title: 'Universal setting is "paged"; but in some chunks "paged" is turned off'
output:
  html_document:
    df_print: "paged"
---

## Paged

```{r}
(mtcars)[1:2,]
```

## Not paged

```{r, paged.print=FALSE}
(mtcars)[1:2,]
```
````

The output after knitting to HTML:

[image: The output after knitting to HTML]

Comment: This is great.  Thanks!  How did you learn this?  I don't see `paged.print` in the `knitr` options here https://yihui.org/knitr/options/

Comment: You're very welcome! The `page.printed` option is mentioned for instance [here](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/html-document.html#tab:paged) and even more explicitly [here](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/1403). It took some digging for me, too.